# How to tell when a VS 2010 IWpfTextView has fully loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions, visual-studio-sdk

I'm just starting to learn about the VS2010 SDK and am trying to write an extension that highlights text in the VS editor (using C#).

I've started by making changes to the VS ***Editor Text Adornment*** sample.

Can anybody tell me how I can tell when a file has been fully loaded and displayed in the editor window? I wish to highlight further changes made to the code file without highlighting any text that was already in the file when it was first loaded.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question: you can try to use the [ITextView.LayoutChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview.layoutchanged.aspx) and just try to handle all changes of current opened document. Does this work?

Comment: I already use the LayoutChanged event to perform the highlighting. The problem is that when I open a file all of the existing text is immediately highlighted (LayoutChanged is called when the file is opened and the textview is populated) whereas I only want to highlight any new text that is entered (or any changes made to existing text).

Comment: Why you don't want to ignore first LayoutChanged event? This doesn't work?

Comment: There were 4 layout changed events as the file loaded up. I guess it could be a different number depending on the circumstances so no, I can't just ignore the first event. However, I've since discovered there is a change event fired whenever text is changed and I think I can use this more effectively. Thanks for you comments :)

Comment: Yes, you should be using TextChanged, _not_ LayoutChanged to track edits. Still not clear how you avoid the first load though...